# Why won't this project run NetBeans, but it does in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have built a small program for school that runs perfectly when i run it through eclipse, but if I run the same code in NetBeans I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myrunnable/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myrunnable.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: myrunnable.Main.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How do i fix this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used netbeans but from what I can see from your exception looks to me JRE may not be in the classpath. Have you checked that? For example when you create a project in eclipse it will automatically add JRE to the classpath.

OR

may be you need to explicitly compile/build before you can run. In eclipse it is auto too. When you run a simple.java it would have created the corresponding simple.class in the bin output folder.

Check those two areas you will be fine I think

Answer (score 1):

Is there a main method defined in the class?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
```

Also, is your Java JDK properly registered inside Netbeans?